# JSTL fmt:formatDate fail in maven

Tags: maven, jstl

I don't have any exceptions and everything seems to be ok but the formatDate ${now} doesn't return any value. any idea why ?
Here is the jsp head

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

and here is what i use to show the date

```
<p>Formatted Date (3): <fmt:formatDate type="both" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/></p>
```

here is the pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

anything else i should add ?

```
<%Date date=new java.util.Date();
pageContext.setAttribute("now", date);  %>
```

Comment: What is the generated HTML output? What is the value of `now`? Does this attribute even exist?

Comment: You forgot to respond on  "What is the generated HTML output?" question of JB Nizet which is most important question of all. With this information we can see if JSTL tags are properly parsed or not, so we can determine whether a misconfigured JSTL is the cause, or the `${now}` simply not being in the scope.